# best way to optmize insert

Tags: mysql, pdo, transactions

i need to optimize that insert because the file where the data comes from 
now have more than 3000 lines of registers.
i want to know if there is a way to do it more fast
it is taking about 5 minutes
sorry for my poor english.

```
while ( ! feof ( $f ) ) {

    // Ler uma linha do arquivo $linha = fgetcsv ( $f, 0, $delimitador ); if (! $linha) { continue; }

    $conn = $calculo->Connect ();
    $conn->beginTransaction ();

    $stmtOrgao = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orgao () values(null, ?,?)");
    $dadosOrgao = array (
            $linha [0],
            $linha [1]
    );
    $stmtOrgao->execute ( $dadosOrgao );
    $idOrgao = $conn->lastInsertId ();

    $stmtFuncionario = $conn->prepare("insert into funcionario() values(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                                                                             ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                                                                             ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                                                                             ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $dadosFuncionario = array(
        $linha[2],$linha[3],$linha[4],$linha[5],$linha[6],$linha[7],$linha[8],$linha[9],$linha[10],$linha[11],$linha[12],
        $linha[13],$linha[14],$linha[15],$linha[16],$linha[17],$linha[18],$linha[19],$linha[20],$linha[21],$linha[22],
        $linha[23],$linha[24],$linha[25],$linha[26],$linha[27],$linha[28],$linha[29],$linha[30],$linha[31],$linha[32],
        $linha[33],$linha[34],$linha[35],$linha[36],$linha[37],$linha[38],$linha[39],$linha[40],$linha[41],$linha[42],
        $linha[43],$linha[44],$linha[45],$linha[46],$linha[47],$linha[48],$linha[49],$linha[50],$idOrgao);                    

    $stmtFuncionario->execute($dadosFuncionario);
    $idFuncionario = $conn->lastInsertId();

    $stmtFolha = $conn->prepare("insert into folha () values(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                                                                  ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");



    if(preg_match("/[R$]/i", $linha[67]))
    {

        $separar = explode(" ", $linha[67]);
        $lin = $separar[1];
    }
    else
    {

        $lin = $linha[67];
    }



    $dadosFolha = array(
        $linha[51],$linha[52],$linha[53],$linha[54],$linha[55],$linha[56],$linha[57],$linha[58],$linha[59],$linha[60],$linha[61],
        $linha[62],$linha[63],$linha[64],$linha[65],$linha[66],$lin,$linha[68],$linha[117],$linha[118],$linha[119],$linha[120],
        $linha[121],$idFuncionario);

    $stmtFolha->execute($dadosFolha);
    $idFolha =  $conn->lastInsertId();

    $stmtProvento = $conn->prepare("insert into proventos () values(null, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                                                                          ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                                                                          ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    $dadosProvento = array(
        $linha[69],$linha[70],$linha[71],$linha[72],$linha[73],$linha[74],$linha[75],$linha[76],$linha[77],$linha[78],$linha[79],
        $linha[80],$linha[81],$linha[82],$linha[83],$linha[84],$linha[85],$linha[86],$linha[87],$linha[88],$linha[97],$linha[98],
        $linha[99],$linha[100],$linha[101],$linha[102],$linha[103],$linha[106],$linha[107],$linha[108],$linha[109],$linha[110],
        $linha[111],$linha[112],$linha[113],$linha[114],$linha[116],$idFolha);
    $stmtProvento->execute($dadosProvento);

    $stmtDesconto = $conn->prepare("insert into descontos () values(null, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $dadosDesconto= array(
        $linha[89],$linha[90],$linha[91],$linha[92],$linha[93],$linha[94],
        $linha[95],$linha[96],$linha[104],$linha[105],$linha[115],$idFolha);
    $stmtDesconto->execute($dadosDesconto);

    $stmtOutros = $conn->prepare("insert into outros () values(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,                                                                     ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,                                                                     ?,?)");

    $dadosOutros = array(
        $linha[122],$linha[123],$linha[124],$linha[125],$linha[126],$linha[127],$linha[128],$linha[129],$linha[130],$linha[131],
        $linha[132],$linha[133],$linha[134],$linha[135],$linha[136],$linha[137],$linha[138],$linha[139],$linha[140],$linha[141],
        $linha[142],$linha[143],$linha[144],$linha[145],$linha[146],$linha[147],$linha[148],$linha[149],$linha[150],$linha[151],
        $linha[152],$linha[153],$linha[154],$linha[155],$linha[156],$linha[157],$linha[158],$linha[159],$linha[160],$linha[161],
        $linha[162],$idFolha);

    $stmtOutros->execute($dadosOutros);

    $conn->commit();
    $conn=null;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move all of your prepare statements out of the while loop. They only need to be prepared once and then used as many times as you like. This will remove many round trips to the server.

If you know for certain you are not possibly breaking any unique keys, you can drop your keys and indexes before the loop and then recreate them after. This is faster than letting the db update indexes on each insert, but can lead to data issues and other problems if you're not careful. So I only mention this if performance is paramount.

Comment: but in each loop the data comes from a different line of the file if i take out i will have the data just from one line, right

Comment: No a prepared statement is different than running the statement with data. Prepare once, run many times. Try it and see.